# Negate regex in referer analysis

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want find any domain in referer, except my domain (full URL https://www.example.com/AnySubDir).

When I use negate expression bellow,  any string does match, why?

```
(?! (^Referer?:\shttps?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?www\.example\.com(\/|$)(.*)) )
```

Comment: You probably want to anchor your negative lookahead. e.g. if I use `(?!abc)` against `abc`, it will not match at the start, but it will start to match as soon as it passes `a`, because once `a` is passed, there's only `bc` left and this is not `abc` as negated by the lookahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex consists of a negative lookahead only `(?! (^Referer` that will succeed when not matching a space followed by the start of the string Referer etc.. That will match at a lot of postions.

What you could do is move the `^` at the start of the regex and  use a negative lookahead to assert that your string does not start with your url.

```
^(?!Referer: https://www\.example\.com).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJ2yq1/1)

There is no programming language listed, but another way to solve this could be to check if the string starts with `Referer: https://www.example.com`